# Spring boot - Cannot subclass final class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm writing a back end in spring boot. I'm not sure if I've updated a package or what but after a few months of dev, suddenly I got this error on some of my controllers:
`Error creating bean with name 'authApi' defined in file ... Cannot subclass final class`

I've googled it and found some explanations of why `Spring Boot` need classes to be open so I was ready to mark all my classes as `open` but then my auto-wired constructor parameters and properties initialised in place are all null.

Here is an example controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
open class AuthApi(
    private val userManager: UserManager,
    private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
    private val jwtEncoder: JwtEncoder
){
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthApi::class.java)
}
```

Here are my Gradle files. The issue appeared after I've  updated the two submodule's Gradle files to disable `bootJar`. I'm not sure how that could affect the situation but maybe I've cleared some kind of cache and "triggered" an issue I've caused earlyer

Main:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.github.gradle.node.yarn.task.YarnTask

buildscript{
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath("com.github.node-gradle:gradle-node-plugin:3.2.1")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.8"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.5.21"
    id("com.github.node-gradle.node") version "3.2.1"
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
    apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
    apply(plugin = "com.github.node-gradle.node")
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin")
    group = "com.test"
    version = "0.9.0"
    java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin")
    apply(plugin="io.spring.dependency-management")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:3.4.3")
    implementation("com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory:1.9.0")
    implementation("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:2.17.2")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql:1.2.8.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:2.7.8")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.3")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2:2.1.214")
    implementation("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:7.0.5.Final")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30")
    implementation("com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0")
    implementation("com.google.zxing:javase:3.5.0")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.9.0")

    implementation(project(":authentication"))
    implementation(project(":commerce"))

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.0.2")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}
```

Module 1

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar

tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.7.8")
    implementation("com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.23")
    implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:2.0.0")
}
```

Module 2

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar

tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.8")
    implementation("com.stripe:stripe-java:21.2.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.7.8")
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Looking at the debugger, I've found that the original object has all the properties, seems like when I use `userManager` for example in an endpoint, it is accessing the proxy's property or something instead of the original one.

Comment: Things looks perfectly fine, better check what has changed recently in term of configurations/dependencies. Not sure what you use for Logger but that function throws compiler error if you use slf4j.

Comment: I've added my gradle files. The issue appeared when editing those